# Router Additional Assembly from directory

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

Is it possible to add additional assemblies that include routable components by scanning a directory for a Razor Class Library .dll file?

The RCL cannot be referenced in the solution as a project reference neither as a Nuget package.

What I have tried:

`App.razor`

```
@using System.Reflection
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Services

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" 
    AdditionalAssemblies="@ExtraAssemblies">
    <Found>
     //...
   </Found>
   <NotFound>
     //...
   </NotFound>
</Router

@code{
 private static List<Assembly> additionalAssemblies;
 public List<Assembly> ExtraAssemblies
  get{
     if(additionalAssemblies is null)
     {
       //Scan a directory for a .dll to be included
       var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("mypath")
       additionalAssemblies.Add(assembly);
       return additionalAssemblies;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Blazor WebAssembly runs on the client and any paths it uses will be treated as client-side paths. For security reasons a browser can't access local folders by itself and a Blazor app won't load unknown assemblies. [Assembly lazy loading and routing are possible](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-lazy-load-assemblies?view=aspnetcore-6.0) but the assemblies need to be specified [in the project file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-lazy-load-assemblies?view=aspnetcore-6.0#project-file-configuration).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am aware of the Assembly Lazy Loading concept but one of the requirements, is that there must not be project references.
So, that's why I am wondering if it is possible.
Please take a look at the answer with solution I came up with. 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70473545/5993610

Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: What you did is download the assembly then lazily load it, even though you didn't use the built-in lazy loader. You didn't load it from a folder

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by utilizing [GetByteArrayAsync("uri")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getbytearrayasync?view=net-6.0#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_GetByteArrayAsync_System_Uri_)

```
@code{
 [Inject] IHttpClientFactory httpClient {get; set;}
 private static List<Assembly> additionalAssemblies;
 
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
   if(additionalAssemblies is null)
    {
      var http = await httpClient.CreateClient();
      additionalAssemblies = new();
      var path = Path.GetFullPath("mylocalpath");
      var bytes = await http.GetByteArrayAsync(path);
      var assembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);
      additionalAssemblies.Add(assembly);
   }
 }
}
```

In that way, the `assembly` variable contains the Routable Razor Components and is loaded in the `AdditionalAssemblies`

```
@using System.Reflection
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Services

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" 
    AdditionalAssemblies="@additionalAssemblies">
 <Found>
   //...
 </Found>
 <NotFound>
  //...
 </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Looking for feedback.